# How can I pass an unsafe function when a safe function is expected without wrapping the unsafe function?

Tags: rust, ffi

I want to point `pthread_create` to a C function I later link to. That C function will use `pthread_cleanup_push` and `pthread_cleanup_pop` which are C macros and thus cannot be ported to Rust.

This is my code:

```
extern crate libc;
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use libc::c_void;

extern "C" {
    fn thr_fn1(arg:*mut c_void) -> *mut c_void;
}

fn main() {
    let mut tid1 = std::mem::zeroed();
    libc::pthread_create(&mut tid1, null_mut(), thr_fn1, null_mut());
}
```

I expected that since I'm calling libc's FFI anyway, I can just point to an external C function, but I get an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/bin/11-threads/f05-thread-cleanup.rs:25:49
   |
25 |     libc::pthread_create(&mut tid1, null_mut(), thr_fn1, null_mut());
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^ expected normal fn, found unsafe fn
   |
   = note: expected type `extern "C" fn(*mut libc::c_void) -> *mut libc::c_void`
              found type `unsafe extern "C" fn(*mut libc::c_void) -> *mut libc::c_void {thr_fn1}`
```

I could write a wrapper which calls the C function in an `unsafe{}` block, but is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: That just sounds like a bug with libc. Have you considered filing it or asking them to change the signature?

Comment: If you are using Rust code to call C code to which you are going to pass a C function, that leads to the alternative: just call `pthread_create` from your C code and skip the whole song and dance.

Comment: Requiring only safe code to pass to C looks superfluous, but a simple workaround would be to create a `extern "C" fn wrapped_fn1(arg: *mut c_void) -> *mut c_void { unsafe { thr_fn1(arg) } }` and pass `wrapped_fn1` to `pthread_create`. Also, you will need an `unsafe` block in `main` to invoke `libc::pthread_create` and `std::mem::zeroed`.

Answer (score 1):

The `libc` function definition is wrong: The C header `/usr/include/pthread.h`:

```
extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
                           const pthread_attr_t *__restrict __attr,
                           void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
                           void *__restrict __arg) __THROWNL __nonnull ((1, 3));
```

`bindgen` produces this function definition:

```
pub fn pthread_create(arg1: *mut pthread_t,
                      arg2: *const pthread_attr_t,
                      arg3: Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(arg1: *mut c_void) -> *mut c_void>,
                      arg4: *mut c_void) -> c_int;
```

Which compiles both on macOS and Linux. I'm not sure `Option` is a good idea here; why would anyone start a thread which doesn't call a function?

I opened [a PR for `libc`](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/pull/527) to correct the issue (without the `Option` part)

Comment: *I'm not sure `Option` is a good idea here* — because bindgen is an automated tool and there's no way to discern from a function signature if a pointer should or should not be `NULL`.

Comment: @Shepmaster so you also would suggest to not use `Option` here, right?

Comment: Hard to tell. **I** can't see why you would, but calls like this are often rife with overloaded behavior for edge case argumnets.  For example, `kill (2)` allows using PID 0 as an argument even though no process can have PID 0.

Comment: This finding seems unrelated from the error reported in the question. If `arg3` were an `Option`, you should have an error like "expected Option<x>, found<x>", not "expected normal fn, found unsafe fn".

Comment: @user4815162342 the point is more the adding of `unsafe` to the function definition which solved the issue, see also the PR where I only added the unsafe but left out `Option`

Comment: @Shepmaster I went through the man pages and through the section in my unix book (advanced programming in the unix environment) and nowhere does it specify what happens if you give `null` to the fn argument (the 3rd argument). Upon testing it did segfault on Linux upon thread start, and on OSX it "only" segfaulted upon `pthread_join`, so I'd say it's safe to say that this never should be `Null`